# scanf() with C++ enums

Tags: c++, enums

The following is a typical situation in our codebase.

```
enum ConfigOption { CONFIG_1=1, CONFIG_2=2, CONFIG_3=3 }

ConfigOption cfg1, cfg2;

sscanf(s, "%d", &cfg1);
```

This is an internally used simulation software. Not distributed. Ease of maintenance and correctness are important. Portability and user interface -- not really.

The trouble is `enum` in C++ is not necessarily an `int`. So we get a compiler warning, and may get incorrect behavior when using a different compiler or when optimizations are enabled.

One solution is just to cast `&cfg` to `int*`. However this will not catch cases where the compiler had decided to allocate something other than `int` to the `enum`.

So I suggested the following solution:

```
template<typename T> inline
int& eint(T& enum_var) {
    assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(int));
    return (int&)enum_var;
}
```

And now one uses `scanf` as follows:

```
sscanf(s, "%d", &eint(cfg1));
```

I would love to hear opinions and other (better) solutions to the above problem.
Keep in mind that one of the goals is to keep the code simple. This is not 'production-quality' stuff and the more you add -- the more difficult maintenance becomes.

Comment: Since the `sizeof(T)` is evaluated at compile-time, I would suggest a static (compile-time) assertion (e.g `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`), so you'd get a *compiler* error if the size is not correct. And if you do, you can find the offending enum, and fix it using Nils's suggestion below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a modern compiler like vs2010 you can specify the size of the enum elements

```
enum class ConfigOption: unsigned int {CONFIG_1=1, CONFIG_2=2, CONFIG_3=3};
```

its new in C++0x

Comment: Unfortunately we still use an old version of gcc. Still, this seems the cleanest solution, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to force the enum to a minimum size.. That's what Microsoft did for their enums in their DirectX headerfiles (a nice trick I have to admit).

They enforced the size of the enum to be equal to an int by adding a dummy enum like this:

```
typedef enum 
{
  fooo = 1,
  baar = 2,
  ___Force32Bit = ~0UL
} MyEnum;
```

Now the enum will always be **at least** the size of an int.

If you want to you can take this over the top.. This one forces the size of the enum to a long long:

```
typedef enum 
{
  fooo = 1,
  baar = 2,
  ___Force64Bit = ~0ULL
} MyEnum;
```

I know, it is not a super clean solution. I think such a solution does not exist and enforcing a minimum size worked well for me so far. You may have to adjust the code if you go from 32 to 64 bit code, but usually in these situations you have to review some parts of the code anyway, so no big issue.

Btw - sorry for the C-code, I know the question was tagged as C++, but I'm a C-guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read it as an actual `int`?

```
enum ConfigOption { CONFIG_1=1, CONFIG_2=2, CONFIG_3=3 };
ConfigOption cfg1;

int i;
sscanf(s, "%d", &i);
cfg1 = i;
```

And that way you can do more comprehensive validity checks too (such as testing that the read integer is within the range of your `enum` type).

(Of course, if you're at all concerned about detecting errors, for simple parsing like this, you should be using `strtol` or `strtoul` instead of `sscanf`.)

Comment: Correct, but annoying (and you still need a cast for the assigment). We have tons of these...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm), or if you aren't using `boost` and don't want to start using it for just this case, you could just write a simplified version of that yourself. For an example take a look [at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469696/what-is-your-most-useful-c-c-utility/469718#469718).

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` relies on stream operator `<<` and `>>` overloads. It would work with an enum only if those operators are overloaded for this enum.